# Undefined reference to `yylval' and `yyerror`

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to compile an example from book `flex and Bison`. I was wondering why I got the following build error, and how I can correct it?

```
$ make
bison -d fb1-5.y
fb1-5.y: warning: 3 shift/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]
flex fb1-5.l
cc -o  fb1-5.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl
fb1-5.l: In function ‘yylex’:
fb1-5.l:27:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyerror’; did you mean ‘perror’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 . { yyerror("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
   ^~~~~~~
   perror
/tmp/cctl5WLj.o: In function `yylex':
lex.yy.c:(.text+0x32f): undefined reference to `yylval'
lex.yy.c:(.text+0x363): undefined reference to `yyerror'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'fb1-5' failed
make: *** [fb1-5] Error 1
```

Makefile:

```
fb1-5:  fb1-5.l fb1-5.y
    bison -d fb1-5.y
    flex fb1-5.l
    cc -o  fb1-5.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl
```

fb1-5.y

```
/* simplest version of calculator */

%{
#  include <stdio.h>
%}

/* declare tokens */
%token NUMBER
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV ABS
%token OP CP
%token EOL

%%

calclist: /* nothing */
 | calclist exp EOL { printf("= %d\n> ", $2); }
 | calclist EOL { printf("> "); } /* blank line or a comment */
 ;

exp: factor
 | exp ADD exp { $$ = $1 + $3; }
 | exp SUB factor { $$ = $1 - $3; }
 | exp ABS factor { $$ = $1 | $3; }
 ;

factor: term
 | factor MUL term { $$ = $1 * $3; }
 | factor DIV term { $$ = $1 / $3; }
 ;

term: NUMBER
 | ABS term { $$ = $2 >= 0? $2 : - $2; }
 | OP exp CP { $$ = $2; }
 ;
%%
main()
{
  printf("> "); 
  yyparse();
}

yyerror(char *s)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
}
```

fb1-5.l:

```
/* recognize tokens for the calculator and print them out */

%{
# include "fb1-5.tab.h"
%}

%%
"+" { return ADD; }
"-" { return SUB; }
"*" { return MUL; }
"/" { return DIV; }
"|"     { return ABS; }
"("     { return OP; }
")"     { return CP; }
[0-9]+  { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }

\n      { return EOL; }
"//".*  
[ \t]   { /* ignore white space */ }
.   { yyerror("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
%%
```

Comment: `cc: error: fb1-5.tab.c: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your makefile to:

```
fb1-5:  fb1-5.l fb1-5.y
    bison -b fb1-5 -d fb1-5.y
    flex fb1-5.l
    gcc -o fb1-5 fb1-5.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl -ly
```

to produce the correct output file and have a standard implementation of yyerror

Comment: Thanks. WHat exactly are the libraries to link?

Comment: @Tim liby defines a `yyerror()` implementation (if no other one is defined), `-lfl` provides a `yywrap` default implementation. At least on my system, other systems may handle this otherwise. Usually, `-ly` and `-ll` (or `-lfl`) should be specified to be safe on many platforms.

Comment: You have your own implementation of `yyerror()`, so you probably wouldn't need `-ly` for that, but it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the problem is here

```
cc -o   lex.yy.c  fb1-5.tab.c -lfl
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) can you explain why the error in my post? (2) run your command, `cc: error: fb1-5.tab.c: No such file or directory`. (3) Is the output file of `flex` always `lex.yy.c`? Can there be more than one  input flex files in the same directory, and thus overwriting one another?

Comment: @tim: you can tell flex what filename to use with the `-o` option, just like `cc`. In both cases, you need to follow the option with the name of the desired output file. (Which is the problem with your `cc` invocation.)

Comment: are you sure that     bison -d fb1-5.y is actually producing  fb1-5.tab.c?

Comment: no if you are compiling it with the same name it will overwrite it if it compiles successfully

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate issues here.

1. `yyerror` is not declared in your scanner (or, for that mattet in your parser). Bison does not generate a declaration for it so you need to declare it in any translation unit which uses it.
2. `cc -o  fb1-5.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl` tells the C compiler to compile `lex.yy.c` placing the resulting executable (the output of the compiler) into `fb1-5.tab.c`. That's not what you intended. It overwrites the generated parser with an executable, and does not compile the generated parser with the result that symbols defined in the parser are not available to the linker.

Comment: Thanks. (1) `yyerror` is defined in `fb1-5.y`. (2)  `cc -o fb-1.5 fb1-5.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl -ly` doesn't work, because `cc: error: fb1-5.tab.c: No such file or directory`

Comment: @tim: the fact that `yyerror` is defined in the parser does not make its declaration available in the lexer. The compiler is complaining that yyerror is undeclared, which is different from the linker complaining that it is undefined.

Comment: I don't know why bison isn't creating `fb1-5.tab.c`; it probably had to do with some wierdness in your distro. Add `-o fb1-5.tab.c` to your bison command.

Comment: I used the make file in the book, which seems not correct.

Comment: @tim: the makefile in the book says `-o $@`. You left out the `$@`. (But `$@` is a make syntax. It won't work on the command line.)

Comment: why does the book not specify `-ly`? Is it not needed? WHat exactly are the libraries to link?

Comment: @tim: really neither -ly nor -lfl are necessary. Both libraries define a default implementation of `main()`. (The one in `-ly` calls `yyparse` and the one in `-lfl` calls `yylex`.) `-lfl` also contains a default implementation of `yywrap`; instead add `%option noyywrap` to your flex prologue.

Comment: What does `bison --version` print? And what about `which bison`?

Comment: Are the two libraies needed by the program and  linking?  If yes, how does `cc` find them?  `bison (GNU Bison) 3.0.4` `/usr/bin/bison`

Comment: What line to add to flex file? I find that without `-lfl` `cc` reports error, while without `-ly` it works still, and I still don't understand the reason.

Comment: @tim: please reread my previous comment (starting "really neither")